# Sum with SQL depending on the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, window-functions

I have 3 columns : `year`, `price`, and `day_type`.

```
year day_type price
2016 0 10
2016 1 20
2016 2 5
2017 0 14
2017 1 6
2017 2 3
```

I want to keep only the lines where `day_type = 1 or 2`, but add to these lines the value when `day_type = 0`.

Expected Result :

```
year day_type price
2016 1 30
2016 2 15
2017 1 20
2017 2 17
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
select t.year, t.day_type, (t.price + coalesce(t0.price, 0)) as price
from t left join
     t t0
     on t.year = t0.year and t0.day_type = 0
where t.day_type <> 0;
```

This uses `left join` in case one of the years does not have a `0` price.

Answer (score 1):

With `sum()` window function:

```
select * from (
  select year, (2 * day_type) % 3 as day_type,
  sum(price) over (partition by year) - price as price
  from tablename 
) t
where day_type <> 0
order by year, day_type
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54e857328a6978ad4adaaca6ec72e3b7).
Results:

```
year | day_type | price
---: | -------: | ----:
2016 |        1 |    30
2016 |        2 |    15
2017 |        1 |    20
2017 |        2 |    17
```